# Custom Object and EventListeners

Tags: javascript, html, oop, dom-events

I am attempting to write my own button object in JavaScript that can be placed on an HTML5 canvas. The problem I am having is with adding the event listener to my function. My assumption is that I need to extend an object that actually has the `addEventListener` method, but I am unsure how to do this in JavaScript. Below is a snippet of some of my code:

```
function Button(bContext, ...) {
    var self = this;
    var context = bContext;
    ...


    self.addEventListener('mouseover', self.mouseOverListener, false);
    ...

    self.drawMe = function() {
    ...
    };

    self.mouseOverListener = function() {
        alert("Hovering");
    };
};
```

The '...' is just me shortening the code for this post, in actuality there is a lot more stuff there but it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Good question, but I doubt it's implementable by extending an HTML element. It's not possible to initialize an HTML element like `new HTMLDivElement` either, so I'm not sure if you can extend one.

Comment: Well you could extend the prototype, but you cannot bring a new type of DOM node into existence.  You'll have to catch events on the `<canvas>` element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add the `addEventListener` method to your object (in most browsers anyway, might not work in `IE < 8`)

```
self.addEventListener = document.body.addEventListener
```

However, it won't magically start triggering click events when it's clicked.  You'd still have to generate those yourself by monitoring events on the `<canvas>` element. As such, it's **definitely** better to just roll your own event listener, or incorporate one from an existing library (see below) than try to inherit from the DOM one, as that can get sketchy.

Odds are pretty high that you'll just want to use a `<canvas>` library like [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).  Which has all of this stuff baked in, and impliments it's own `Element` object with DOM-like events.  That said, if you *really* want to roll your own solution, it's pretty straightforward as long as you only want to capture click events inside rectangular areas (finding points on curved elements is another matter).

Here's some quick pseudocode

```
var buttons = []; // stores all button instances
var canvas = document.getElementById('#myCanvas');
canvas.bind('mousemove',function(event){
  var i = buttons.length;
  while(i--){
    var box = { 
       x: [buttons[i].x, buttons[i].pos.x+buttons[i].width], 
       y: [buttons.y, buttons[i].pos.y+buttons[i].height]
    };
    if(event.clientX > box.x[0] && event.clientX < box.x[1] && event.clientY > box.y[0] && event.clientY < box.y[1]){
       buttons[i].click();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was afraid it would not be so easy.  Anyway, thanks for the post I will probably end up doing it the way you suggested in the pseudocode unfortunalty I now have to write all three mouse events I intended on using.